# Checkout branch specified in .gitmodules for each submodule?

Tags: git-submodules

I have submodules at many different paths. Some submodules are in the root of our repository, most are in src/app/shared-comps, but many are scattered throughout. When I clone our project, the branches for submodules are all in detached HEAD state, and I want to set them on the branches specified in .gitmodules file. I currently do this manually like so:

```
cd submodule1 && git checkout master && cd .. &&
cd src/app/shared-comps &&
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh \
    -c "(echo {} && cd {} && git checkout our-fork && echo)" \;
# so on and so forth
```

How can I have a script that avoids hard-coding `submodule1` goes on master branch, and `src/app/shared-comps` should all go on `our-fork`? In fact, if some shared-comps should not be on `our-fork` branch, but perhaps master, how can we have them go to whatever branch is specified in .gitmodules?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to set submodules to be on the branch set in .gitmodules, you can run this:

```
git submodule foreach 'git checkout `git config -f $toplevel/.gitmodules submodule.$sm_path.branch`'
```

This is best run when setting up a new project from scratch.

When you do a git pull and branch names change, you'll need to run it again. I am not sure of a git hook that could do this for you. Git doesn't have a `post-pull` hook where you can do these things

(I would put this in comment but need formatting - regarding a post-pull hook, I did notice husky printed this after my co-worker did a vanilla `git pull` inside WSL

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775
    throw err;
    Error: Cannot find module 'nice-try'
 - /mnt/d/work/dev/projects/mhp-new/node_modules/husky/node_modules/cross-spawn/lib/parse.js
 - /mnt/d/work/dev/projects/mhp-new/node_modules/husky/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js    
 - /mnt/d/work/dev/projects/mhp-new/node_modules/husky/node_modules/execa/index.js
 - /mnt/d/work/dev/projects/mhp-new/node_modules/husky/lib/runner/index.js
 - /mnt/d/work/dev/projects/mhp-new/node_modules/husky/lib/runner/bin.js
 - /mnt/d/work/dev/projects/mhp-new/node_modules/husky/run.js

      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:772:15)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:27)
      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/d/work/dev/projects/mhp-new/node_modules/husky/node_modules/cross-spawn/lib/parse.js:4:17)
      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19) {
        code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
        requireStack: [
            '/mnt/d/work/dev/projects/mhp-new/node_modules/husky/node_modules/cross-spawn/lib/parse.js',
            '/mnt/d/work/dev/projects/mhp-new/node_modules/husky/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js', 
            '/mnt/d/work/dev/projects/mhp-new/node_modules/husky/node_modules/execa/index.js',       
            '/mnt/d/work/dev/projects/mhp-new/node_modules/husky/lib/runner/index.js',
            '/mnt/d/work/dev/projects/mhp-new/node_modules/husky/lib/runner/bin.js',
            '/mnt/d/work/dev/projects/mhp-new/node_modules/husky/run.js'
        ]
```